# Selenium IDE unable to capture Kendo Grid click

Tags: selenium

We are using selenium to capture data flows and click on data on Kendogrid. When playback, the IDE fails to properly capture the clicked data on kendogrid. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Isn't easy to test the Kendo UI elements, but isn't possible.

If you're testing the prev and next buttons, you'll not find any problem; but, if you're testing the Kendo Grid filters probably you'll need to check the generated code via Firebug.

In my case, If I don't know the id of the html element, I click on the button `Click To Record` to capture the element and later test. But sometimes I get a surprise: isn't the correctly code captured by the recorder. In this cases, you need to check manually what's the correct code and discard what code don't you need (the Selenium IDE provides you the possible code cases via right click over the html element).

I recommend you to check the generated code of your site using Firebug to see how the grid was generated. If you want something more completely to test, use Selenium Web Driver (Selenium IDE has some limitants).

I hope this will help you.